# Python Tkinter, avoid code repetition by bring a variable when going to a new window (a new class)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

first question ever asked!

I am new to both Python and Tkinter and followed this guide to create multiple windows with Tkinter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&index=4

When the user makes a choice in the first window, lets say we have a button for each month, and three of the buttons (june, july, august) represents Summer.

Like this:

```
months = ["january", "february" and so on]

for i in months[0:2]:
    button = tk.Button(self, text=i, command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageWinter)).pack()

for i in months[2:5]:
    button = tk.Button(self, text=i, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSpring)).pack()
```

Now the thing is that I have created a class for each season. It works fine but, except the season, all the code is just the same, so I would like to create just one class. Code repetition just is not pretty :) My problem is that I have no idea how (or if it even is possible) to bring the users choice of month (that represents a certain season) to the class.

Now I have four different classes like this:

```
class PageSpring(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

     a whole lot of code
     ...
     ...
     season=Spring

     more code....

        mlabel3=tk.Label(self, text="Results:").pack()
        mlabel4=tk.Label(self, text=pres).pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Startpage",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack()
```

Instead I would like one class like this, where the season is brought with the users choice, somehow. None of the ways I have tried have worked, the season just keeps on getting undefined or something else is missing.

```
class Season(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

     a whole lot of code
     ...
     ...     
     more code....

        mlabel3=tk.Label(self, text="Results:").pack()
        mlabel4=tk.Label(self, text=pres).pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Startpage",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack()
```

But How can I bring the season to this generalized class?

Answer (score 2):

You send the season to the generalized class in the same way you sent `self`, `parent`, and `controller` to it: pass it in as an argument.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller, season):
```

Also, don't chain geometry management with widget creation. Instead of:

```
mybutton = Button(parent).pack()
```

do:

```
mybutton = Button(parent)
mybutton.pack()
```

It may seem redundant, but what ends up happening with the shorter version is that `button` is not really a `Button` - it's `None`, as returned by `pack()`. It's more useful to save a `Button` than `None`.

Comment: Great comment about the chain geometry management. I have seen most people do like you suggested but I have not understood why up until now. Thank you!

As stated Im really new to Python (and programming),  my mind is just starting to grasp the way classes work. I built my program just like sentdex in the video (with a SeaofBTCapp-class and a StartPage-class) but when I try to add season I just recieve "'season' is not defined". Any ideas? Would it be helpful if i posted more of the code?

At least I know what I need to do to resolve my troubles, just need to learn how now :)

Thanks again!

Comment: If you do `season=Spring` as you do in your code, `Spring` is a variable which you should define before using. If you just want to be able to ask the object what season it is, you can assign a simple string to it, such as `season="spring"`. I'd also recommend specifying an object's own attributes with `self`, e.g. `self.season = "spring"`.

Comment: Progress! I have made it down to one class just as I wished for, but instead of adjusting the season depending on the choice the user makes it just continues with the default season (spring, in this case). Here is how it looks right now:
    
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        
        for i in months[0:2]:
            season="Winter"
            button = tk.Button(self, text=i, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSeason)).pack()

(have also tried with self.parent="Winter", but this last part is tricky)

Comment: The new generel class looks like this:
class PageSeason(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, season, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,season)